# Safari confuses browsing context when using 'download' attribute on anchors

Tags: html, safari

Safari (v11.0.3 for example) now supports `download` attribute on anchor elements, BUT, using them will break other links on the page which use the `_blank` target browsing context.

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/file_to_download" download>Download</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="/view.html" target="_blank">View</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. Click on "View", browser opens page in new window.
2. Click on "Download", browser downloads the file requested.
3. Click on "View" again, browser **downloads** the page rather then open a new window.

Change the target attribute of the View anchor, and there are no problems (...except you'll not open a new window, of course.)

Other browsers handle this as expected, downloading one, viewing the other.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Omg, I knew I wasn't the only one on this. This is so frustrating that I spent so much time to address the issue but something is wrong with Safari. I can confirm. I have buttons in a html form. And a third button's click triggers js function and js function creates dummy a element and sets "download" attribute with a filename then clicks itself and removes the element afterwards. However, that process breaks all the other buttons and links and the form itself. any button in the form downloads the result from form's action address and links does the same.